# Time conversion by Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date

I have a problem generated by rails...

My mysql db saves the dates in this format:

> 2011-08-05 14:07:24 +0200

This kind of date gets generated by the created_at function:

When I use the `Time.now` function, the format is:

```
Fri Aug 05 14:07:24 +0200 2011
```

Unfortunately those two dates are not compatible for mysql...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you pass your time variable to the model? If you pass like `Time.now` as a `Time` object then Rails converts the format to the correct SQL format.

So do not pass it as a `String`

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %T %z')
# => "2011-08-05 14:19:35 +0200"
```